# arrays containing string indexes

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list

In python, a list, even when it is a class, prohibits its instances from creating more user attributes.

```py
>> x = list()
>> x.new_attribute = 90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'new_attribute'
```

This as expected throws error even when classes could possibly accept more attributes through `__dict__`. This makes sense.

Even though it isn't exactly similar, my questions is that javascript arrays act weirdly when they are given properties.

```js
let x = [1,2,3]
x.foo = "this is unexcpected"
console.log(x)
```

This would print `[1, 2, 3, foo: "this is unexcpected"]`. Here is my **questions**, Aren't arrays supposed to have all their keys to be autogenerated numbers? I mean if I check the length it is still three and it isn't counting `foo` as part of the array in the usual sense, more over all the methods like pop doesn't apply to the `key-value` pair. This makes a good sense, but makes me wounder if this (addition of key-value pairs) is allowed so that they could be used to store metadatas about the arrays, after all length is also kind of a property. One more questions, if arrays can store key-value pairs, what makes them different from object except some of the methods like inserting, poping ...?

Comment: No. Arrays are objects, so they can have any property names an object has. They're a special kind of objects because of the Array.prototype object, with its methods. Also note that they are understood as being "special" by things like `JSON.stringify()`, which will ignore non-numeric property names.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I find the question interesting...

The main part of the question is what's the difference between an object and an array. As mentioned in the comments, `Array.prototype` IS an object. Which allows us to do some kind of weird things. Take this code for example:

```
let y = [0,1,2,3];
y.foo = "Testing";
console.log(y);
y.sample = function(){
    console.log("Hello world");
}

y.sample()
```

Yes, you can add methods to an array, on the console it outputs this:

```
> (4) [0, 1, 2, 3, foo: 'Testing']
    0: 0
    1: 1
    2: 2
    3: 3
    foo: "Testing"
    sample: ƒ ()
    length: 4
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

> Hello World
```

Considering the way that Javascript was made, we can do odd things like add methods to arrays and treat them as objects. However, these objects have intended uses and built-in methods provided by the developers (push, pop, etc.). Maybe you could create your own modified datatype in JS by modifying the `Array.prototype` object. Outside of that, it feels kinda weird to add methods and properties to arrays...at that point just make an object for the sake of readability, but hey, as long as your code is understandable and it works, it's good to me.